# Android - Rate format pattern in strings.xml throws UnknownFormatConversionException when getString() called

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to store a rate format in `strings.xml` and use `getString()` at run-time to format a string in that format. I have this pattern in my `strings.xml`:

```
<string name="rate_format">%1$s\%</string>
```

Suppose I call `getString(R.string.rate_format, "11")` at run-time. Then I'd expect "11%" to be returned. However, this call is throwing a `UnknownFormatConversionException`.

Am I missing something? This is how we are supposed to be escaping the percent sign, right?

Answer (score 0):

So, this pattern in `strings.xml` fixes it and I have NO IDEA WHYYYYYYY. Someone help me out I'm losing my mind here.

```
<string name="rate_format">%1$s%%</string>
```